# Get browser time format Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, datetime-format

Is there a method to get the time format from the OS or browser in Angular, because I need to show time in user format?!

I tried to find something, but without any result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By format do you mean a string like `DD.MM.YYYY`?. Also what is your end goal?

Comment: Yes, but for time, like HH:MM:SS XM. I need to show time in a table column based on user browser or OS format

Comment: You can’t do that reliably. Far better to present dates in an unambiguous format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to format time is using the browser built-in [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

```js
const now = new Date()

console.log(
  "American: %s \nLocal: %s \nWith Seconds: %s \nHour cycle: %s",
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {timeStyle: "short"}).format(now),
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeStyle: "short"}).format(now),
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeStyle: "medium"}).format(now),
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeStyle: "short"}).resolvedOptions().hourCycle
)
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat):

> hourCycle
> The hour cycle to use. Possible values are "h11", "h12", "h23", or "h24".

Comment: The output from *Intl.DateTimeFormat* is implementation dependent and not fully supported on all platforms. On iPad, none of the above show the time, Hour cycle shows “undefined”.

Comment: There is a [polyfill](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-datetimeformat/) to add support for browsers that don't support it

Answer (score 1):

Typically time format depends on user locale. You can easily get LOCALE_ID and then [format date](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#format-data-based-on-locale)

then you can use js function: `toLocaleTimeString()`

Easiest way to do it will be with moment.

```
// From 2.8.1 onward
moment.locale(String);
```

Comment: This assumes that the user has set the browser to their preferred language, and that the browser allows such settings at all. Many don’t and just default to en-us.